# Which Event to use in aspx page to read POSTed data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I have seen 100 examples of posting from a HTML form to a .aspx page and using `Request.Form` to see the values; this makes sense.

I'm trying to build up a small example to mimic a project where data is posted to a *blank* .aspx page and the values just read server side. I know it seems odd to leverage a `.aspx` page for this purpose, but that's the objective.

I want to know *which* event will be raised on the server in my `Default.aspx` page when data is POSTed to it? I doub't `Page_Load()` fires because the page is not being pyhsically opened, rather just hosted in IIS on the server.

Which event will I use in `Default.aspx` to read or siphon out the POSTed data?

**EDIT:** '*mimic*' is the keyword here. This is not a new project, but I don't have the source for the original - it's a prototype to mimic an implemented example. If I was starting from scratch exposing something to POST data I'd most likely choose WebAPI nowadays.

Comment: This is conceptually a web service.  There is functionality *specifically* for this.  You shouldn't be using an .aspx file for this, you'll be using an ashx file.

Comment: sounds as you need http handler or ashx file. I believe, as long as you call aspx file, Page_Load will be called because it is part of page lifecycle

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "blank". If you're going to post form fields, then it has to contain a `<form>` tag at the very least, or an AJAX call.

Comment: Imagine if you posted data through query string. On empty page there will be no other way to retrieve it but on Page_load.

Comment: @T.S. Why is that?  You could use almost any event that exists.  You could execute code on pre render, on post render, on initialization, on rendering, on unload, etc.  They all run, even if you're only rendering a blank page.

Comment: In that sense - yes. But they are similar to Page_load because they are "regular page events". I mean, empty page will not have a "control event"

Comment: @T.S. Correct, that is the one and only event that isn't going to exist in this case.  That is a completely different statement from saying that `PageLoad` is the only event.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I should have clarified 'blank'. By that I meant no visible controls. If you were to bring up the page in a browser it would display nothing and be blank. That's not to say as you mentioned it still would contain a `<form>` tag and required header, etc. I probably should have said 'empty' maybe.

Comment: @Servy - Great point. I added an 'Edit' to my post to clarify the constraints OF THE QUESTION.

Comment: Sorry about the caps! Yikes :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Page_Load()
```

If the page has no content and its *sole purpose* is to receive these values, then `Page_Load()` would be the sensible place to capture the values and pass them along to wherever they need to go in the business logic.

> I doub't Page_Load() fires because the page is not being physically opened

Sure it is, at least as far as the page itself is concerned.  How the client requests the page and what the client does with the response from the page is immaterial in this regard.  If the page is requested, it's "loaded" server-side and returned as the response.

> I know it seems odd to leverage a .aspx page for this purpose, but that's the objective.

Very odd indeed.  Though not uncommon.  An ASHX handler may suit your needs more effectively, as might a WCF service endpoint.  But without more information about what you're building and how it's going to be maintained, this is all hearsay.